# Is it possible to convert with a class-type parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Imagine I have 3 different `System.Serializable` classes, let's put them in one line/class:

```
[System.Serializable] public class ClassA { public string xx; }
[System.Serializable] public class ClassB { public int yy; }
[System.Serializable] public class ClassC { public bool zz; }
```

Here's the function I'd like to make (*the code is **not** working*):

```
void MyConvertFunction(
    [System.Serializable] MyClassType,
    string astring_toconvert
) {
    MyClassType j = null;
    j = JsonUtility.FromJson<MyClassType>(astring_toconvert);
    Debug.Log(j);
}
MyConvertFunction(ClassA, "thestring");
MyConvertFunction(ClassB, "1548");
MyConvertFunction(ClassC, "true");
```

*The code above is **not** working*, is there a way to make it work?

Comment: I am not familiar with Unity3d, but in C# you can solve the problem by making `MyConvertFunction` generic on the type, i.e. `MyConvertFunction<ClassA>("thestring");`

Comment: Read [ask] and explain how this code isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to do this with generics. I have a feeling that you also want the returned converted back to that type that is passed in since you are using the `JsonUtility.FromJson` function. Just make the `MyConvertFunction` function return generic then use the `Convert.ChangeType` function for the conversion. I will cover both.

Your class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ClassA { public string xx; }
[System.Serializable]
public class ClassB { public int yy; }
[System.Serializable]
public class ClassC { public bool zz; }
```

The generic convert function

```
T MyConvertFunction<T>(string astring_toconvert)
{
    object resultValue = JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(astring_toconvert);

    //Convert back to the type of object passed into it
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(resultValue, typeof(T));
}
```

**USAGE**:

```
ClassA classA = MyConvertFunction<ClassA>("thestring");
ClassB classB = MyConvertFunction<ClassB>("1548");
ClassC classC = MyConvertFunction<ClassC>("true");
```

Comment: There are a lot of informations that solve many questions I was about to ask. Type conversion, `object` using, generic, and 2 other ones. You're the man! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that;

```
    void MyConvertFunction(Type type, string astring_toconvert)
    {
        var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(astring_toconvert, type);
    }

    MyConvertFunction(typeof(ClassA), "thestring");
    MyConvertFunction(typeof(ClassB), "1548");
    MyConvertFunction(typeof(ClassC), "true");
```

I suggest you to create a interface or base class for `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC`. Because you might want to cast returning deserialized object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JSON convertsion, the format in your examples is wrong.
`"thestring"` can't be converted to ClassA, the correct JSON format is `{"xx": "thestring"}`.

So if you can change the input, Rainman's answer will do.

If you can't change the input, and have to get "thestring" or "123" to convert to ClassA or ClassB, then you'll need to jump through some hoops:

```
void MyConvertFunction(Type type, string astring_toconvert)
{
    var inst = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // create an instance of your class
    var prop = type.GetProperties().First(); // find the property we need to set
    var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(astring_toconvert, prop.PropertyType); // convert the string to the correct type, throwing an exception if can't convert
    prop.SetValue(inst, convertedValue);

    Debug.Log(inst);
}
```

Note that this will only work if you have just one property on your classes. If you have more than one, you'll have to provide correct JSON input.